# WSO2 ESB - nodes not joining the cluster

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, esb

I configured an ESB cluster following this documentation 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Clustered+Deployment but I still got a problem.

In each ESB nodes I got this log

```
WARN - CarbonEventManagementService CEP started with clustering enabled, but SingleNode configuration given.
```

instead of this one

```
INFO - RpcMembershipRequestHandler Received JOIN message from
```

Is there a way to have more details on the log to get what is wrong ?
I can post configuration files if someone can help ^^

Thanks !

Comment: Yes. Posting your configuration files would be _very_ helpful.

Comment: Please post your axis2.xml

Comment: Here is the manager config: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9XJS2RMBbsTaEVtSXB5RE1SSm8
and the worker: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9XJS2RMBbsTMWFNMkIzZHlGSVE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using hostnames for `localMemberHost` and `<member>` section in `axis2.xml`, change them to use IPs instead.

Comment: I managed to make worker join the cluster by updating the registry.xml:
`indexingFrequencyInSeconds` from 2 to 6
`batchSize` from 50 to 25
`indexerPoolSize` from 50 to 5